# Creating Classes in Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I am trying to write classes and execute wherever I need in soap UI using groovy script step.
But it is showing error as :

> "org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: 
>   No signature of method: excel.main() is applicable for argument types: 
>   ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]] Possible solutions: wait(), 
>   wait(long), find(), any(), wait(long, int), find(groovy.lang.Closure)

```
 import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
 import java.io.*;
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
 import java.util.Iterator;

    class excel {
         static void ReadWriteExcel(String a,int b) 
             {            
                 def projectPath = new 
                 com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context).projectPath 
                 //gets the path of the project root
                 FileInputStream fIpStream= new 
                 FileInputStream(projectPath+"\\Bat_File_Data.xls")
                 HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fIpStream);
                 HSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);              
                 int noOfRows = worksheet.getLastRowNum();      
                 int noOfColumns = worksheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
                 for (int i=1;i<2;i++)
                     {  
                        //def res = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(0);
                        def res = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(1);
                        //log.info res         
                         Row row = worksheet.createRow(i);
                         Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
                         Cell cell1 = row.createCell(3);
                         cell.setCellValue(a);             
                         cell1.setCellValue(b);
                     }     
            fIpStream.close(); //Close the InputStream
            FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new 
            File(projectPath+"\\Bat_File_Data.xls"));  
            wb.write(output_file);
            output_file.close();      

    }  
}
        class Groovy 
        {
            static void main(String[] args)
                {
                ReadWriteExcel("Pass",2234);
                } 
        }
```

Comment: Are you using `readyapi`? or open source edition software? If you write the above script in a groovy script test step and trying to call in another step? then it does not work with above approach. You need to compile the class & create jar file and place it under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory, restart soapui tool before start using it.

Comment: Please look at the this thread to see how to achieve that - http://rupertanderson.com/blog/1-how-to-develop-add-and-use-a-custom-groovy-library-in-soapui/

Answer (score 2):

in groovy script you can declare and access static methods of it like this:

```
class A{
    static void greet(String name){
        println "hello $name!"
    }
}

//code without class declaration will be executed as part of script.run() method 
A.greet("world")
```

Comment: Hi Rao,am using Open source Soap UI, i did the process which u have said, but could not work out. can u please suggest me any other answer

Answer (score 1):

In Soapui, without compiling anything, you can use a class like that:

```
class A{
   def log
   def context
   def testRunner

   def A(logIn,contextIn,testRunnerIn){
      this.log = logIn
      this.context = contextIn
      this.testRunner = testRunnerIn
   }

   def method(){
       //your code
   }
//log, context, testRunner are global variables in Soapui
context.setProperty( "A", new A( log, context, testRunner) )
```

then, call your class with `context.A.method()`

if you're in another teststep, you can use : 
    `context.workspace.getProjectByName("ProjectName").getTestSuiteByName("TESTSUITE").testCases["TESTCASE"].testSteps["TESTSTEP"].run(testRunner, context)`
    `context.A.method()`
 to run your class outside your groovy step