# Reusing the groovy code in multiple Groovy Script test steps of SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I created functions(methods)in step1 using groovy in soapUI(open source) and calling in step2, it is not getting called, It is getting called only to that step1. I want to make those functions as global. can any one suggest me how to do that?

Comment: First of all: what the hell do you mean? Second of all, show us some code, what you've tried, what you know that is or isn't working.

Comment: If you don't want to compile your classes, you can create classes and use them everywhere with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841836/creating-classes-in-groovy-script/45934444#45934444). If not, you can use the @Rao solution.

Comment: kandukuri, have you got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve, what you are looking for is, to do the following:

- Create classes (either in `groovy or java` of your preferred language)
- Add the reusable methods into those classes
- Compile the classes and create jar file
- Copy the jar under `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory
- Restart the soapui tool

Now you should be able to call the reusable method from any of your project /test suite / test case/ test step.

Hope this is useful.