# Creating a class in Groovy script encounters an error

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to create a Groovy script based on this example:
[Creating Classes in Groovy Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841836/creating-classes-in-groovy-script)

But I ended up getting this error:

`One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement, the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name. Solutions are to change the file name or to change the class name.`

This is how I created my class:

```
class Test {
    static void greet() {

    }
}

Test.greet()
```

I used to call a method directly when creating a Groovy script like this:

```
test()

public void test() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are named your script as Test.groovy
Try to rename it or change the name of the Test class